# Apply number format on pivot fields

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am able to apply NumberFormat on pivot fields using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotFields property. But that will not apply same format to summed fields. Is there any separate property for summed fields in pivot table that I am missing ?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotFields pFields = pivotTable.PivotFields();
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField pf in pFields)
            if (pf.DataType == XlPivotFieldDataType.xlNumber)
                pf.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00";
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can not set the number format on the exel sheet/column/row that the pivot table is created on?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on these members isn't exactly crystal clear, but after a bit of digging around and trial and error it looks like the property you want is `PivotTable.VisibleFields`, which you need to cast to a `PivotFields` object to iterate through:

```
Excel.PivotFields vFields = (Excel.PivotFields)pivotTable.VisibleFields;
```

This will give you all visible fields in the table (as opposed to `PivotTable.PivotFields()` which only seems to give you the row labels column and the underlying source data). You might have to check the value of each one before you set the number format otherwise I believe it will apply it to everything in the table, which might not be what you want:

```
foreach (Excel.PivotField pf in vFields)
{
    if (pf.DataType == Excel.XlPivotFieldDataType.xlNumber
        & pf.Value == "Sum of Price")
    {
        pf.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00";
    }
}
```

If you wanted to get to one cell in particular, then you can access the `PivotField.PivotItems` and iterate through those for each `PivotField` object:

```
    Excel.PivotItems pi = (Excel.PivotItems)pf.PivotItems();
```

But I think most of the properties of `PivotItem` are read-only.